# Domain of the function $f(2sin x)$ if domain of the function $f(x)$ is $[0,1]$?

Tags: functions

Domain of the function $f(2sin x)$ if domain of the function $f(x)$ is $[0,1]$

This was a question in my text book so upon solving it i came to the answer that the domain of the function $$f(2sinx)  = [2n\pi , 2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{6}]$$

but the answer in my text book is as followed

$$x\in\bigcup_{n\in i}\{[2n\pi , 2n\pi +\frac{\pi}{6}] \bigcup[2n\pi + \frac{5\pi}{6},(2n+1)\pi]\}$$

I am not able to understand the second part $[2n\pi + \frac{5\pi}{6},(2n+1)\pi]$ came from can anyone explain it

Thanks

Akash

Comment: what would be $\sin(\frac{5\pi}{6})$?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the sine function is symmetric about $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. In particular, we have $0\le \sin x \le \frac{1}{2}$ in the interval $0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{6}$ **and also** in the interval $\frac{5\pi}{6}\le x\le \pi$.

This takes care of all the numbers in the interval $[0,2\pi)$. The others can be obtained by adding integer multiples of $2\pi$.